# installing numpy using pip3 in windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am new in python. I have installed python 3.5.1  in windows 10 and now i want to install numpy package . Pip3 is already in my scripts folder but i could not install package by using

```
pip3 install numpy
```

here is the actual command line  command and error

```
PS C:\Users\user\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\python35-32> pip3 install numpy
pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip3 install numpy
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\user\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\python35-32>
```

how can i fix this . Help will be appreciated

Comment: Alternatively you can try `py -3 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: You must be in a cmd window, not at a powershell prompt...

Comment: I would run `get-pip.py` again.  you can grab it from the internet, it should get everything setup properly -- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Answer (score 2):

Compiling numpy on Windows is not trivial. If you're new to it, best use precompiled binaries, from Anaconda or EPD distributions, or from Christoph Gohlke.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  I have installed Anaconda and  then install numpy  but i could not import the  numpy  module in my pyshell
[Anaconda3] C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>conda install numpy
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    --------
    numpy-1.11.0               |           py35_1         2.8 MB

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to add `pip` to your PATH. Or you can run `python -m pip install numpy`. `Numpy` will probably want to compile itself, so you gonna need `c++` compiler for python. [Check here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue where I was unable to run the code for using the array object of `numpy`.

Even though in my `pyCharm` it showed as imported.

And `intellisense` appeared.

What I did:

1. Upgrade pip
   `$python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Uninstalled the previous numpy:
   `$pip uninstall numpy`
3. Install numpy 
   `$pip install numpy`

This worked fine for me and the code executed/interpreted as expected.